# OpenGL: Rendering sprites of variable sizes

Tags: opengl, directx, sprite

I have a particle system to model sand flow simulations. I came across the CUDA SDK **particles** example which I modified to handle particles of different sizes. The positions and colors per particle are stored in VBOs and I added a VBO for the radius attribute. The physics aspect is fine. In rendering, lies my problem:-

The example implements a vertex shader which uses GL_POINT_SPRITE_ARB (its an NVidia extension ), which takes a fixed particle radius. I googled extensively but found no way to make the sprites take variable radii from the particle radius VBO.

The vertex shader looks like this :

```
#define STRINGIFY(A) #A

// vertex shader
const char *vertexShader = STRINGIFY(
    uniform float pointRadius;  // point size in world space
    uniform float pointScale;   // scale to calculate size in pixels
    uniform float densityScale;
    uniform float densityOffset;
    void main()
    {
        // calculate window-space point size
        vec3 posEye = vec3(gl_ModelViewMatrix * vec4(gl_Vertex.xyz, 1.0));
             float dist = length(posEye);
        gl_PointSize = pointRadius * (pointScale / dist);

        gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_MultiTexCoord0;
        gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * vec4(gl_Vertex.xyz, 1.0);

        gl_FrontColor = gl_Color;
    }
);
```

How do I get varying sized point sprites to render ?

NB:- This is a workstation app, so using OpenGL ES isn't an option.

I'd also like to ask about the viability of 2 solutions I came up with:-

1. Using glusphere(), followed by translate and scaling. But I'm afraid this might take a performance hit, from having to render all those extra vertices.
2. Ditch OpenGL and port the entire thing to Direct3D 9 which I believe has a built-in attribute which accepts variable sprite radii, but there's a time constraint and I don't know anything about DirectX.
3. Can I implement 2 instances of the above vertex shader in the same scene and pass them different pointRadius ?

Comment: Point sprites have been core since GL 2.0.

Comment: ... `GL_POINT_SPRITE_ARB (its an NVidia extension )`. No it is not, `ARB` means Architecture Review Board. Anything with that tacked onto the end is a standard extension that has been approved by the ARB, which includes NV, AMD, Intel, Apple, ... and at one time Microsoft. If it were an NV extension, it would be called `GL_POINT_SPRITE_NV`.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman is right. Its not, however I left out some code in the draw function which used the NV extension. Turns out that was causing the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I googled extensively but found no way to make the sprites take variable radii from the particle radius VBO.

1. `glEnable(GL_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE)`
2. Add a `varying float pointSize` and bind your radius VBO there
3. `gl_PointSize = pointSize` in your vertex shader